# What does it mean "Total Monthly Cost for 365 Days"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does it mean "$300 is the Total Monthly Cost for 365 Days"?

Does it mean that one needs to pay 300 every single month and in total it's 3600?
Or does it mean that one needs to pay 300 in total for 12 months?

(Here is the [source](https://www.imglobal.com/img-insurance-plans))

I am a bit confused.

Comment: This does not appear to have been written by a native speaker.  In particular the placement of the dollar sign *after* the number is a common mistake that someone unfamiliar with the conventions of writing in the USA would make.  So Please Tell Us The Source!

Comment: It is an American company allegedly: https://www.imglobal.com/img-insurance-plans. The sign of the dollar is my mistake.

Comment: I can't find the text at that page.  Can you provide some guidance on where that text is to be found?  Is it in the description of one particular insurance plan?

Comment: I agree that it is not clear, and it is not well-written.  But it does sound like something you might find on American financial paperwork - I have had to fill out a lot of it lately myself, so this kind of thing looks familiar.

Comment: That link just leads to an opening page for a new insurance customer. $3600 for a whole year is a lot of insurance. A young driver + big fast car? Worldwide travel insurance for a big family of old people in bad health? Not enough detail.

Comment: I don't see the text you quote. Without further context and clarification, you might right but paying 3,600 dollars per year for travel insurance is very expensive. Is it health insurance, then maybe that's an acceptable price in the US.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised you are confused: it seems designed to confuse.

But *Total Monthly Cost* means the amount you pay each month, so yes, $300 per month, or $3600 over the year.

I have no idea why they say "365 days" rather than "12 months" or "1 year".

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right or wrong.  The phrase is confusing enough that it could mean almost anything.  I don't think we can say it certainly mean  $3600 per year.

Comment: It is from here: https://www.imglobal.com/img-insurance-plans

Comment: @VirtuousLegend - that link is not useful, and provides no information.

Comment: I've just checked it again and it has at least 10 times the same sentence I wrote.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the author wants to point out that **during a specific period of 356 days (a year), the average monthly cost is as written.**
This means that it doesn't necessarily mean the cost will remain the same after said period, or even that a same amount of money is to be paid every single month (rather e.g. $250 in January, but $350 in February).

Since the *cost* is explicitly "monthly", I think you can (only) assume it's $300/month.